# Cross product - how do I know this landing direction is the cross product of the other two?

Tags: vectors

Here is an image:

[image]

I am given $\vec{n}$ and $\vec{v_A}$.

Apparently, $\vec{v_L}$ is perpendicular to the cross product of $\vec{v_A}$ and $\vec{n}$ but I am struggling to see this even with the diagram? And then I am secondly struggling to see which direction I need to cross the vectors in to get the landing direction $\vec{v_L}$

Comment: I don't think $\vec{v_L}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{v_A}$. Maybe I am misunderstanding the diagram.

Comment: @DanDan0101 Sorry I mistyped - I've corrected now to make it clear what I mean

Comment: If $v_L=v_A\times n$, then the diagram is simply incorrect. At least if we are to interpret the gray plane as showing that these three vectors are coplanar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha, I remember doing this a year ago when I was preparing for my further maths A-Level (FP1 :)). The question states that $v_L$ is in the same plane as $v_a$ and n. So it would share the normal vector the plane that $v_a$ and $n$ share. So it's definitely normal to their cross product! Furthermore, the normal vector is perpendicular to along the ground, which is the direction in which the plane is travelling, so it is certainly perpendicular to that. Therefore, we know it must be perpendicular to those two vectors , and we take the cross product.

Now, for the direction, you can do that by the right hand rule!.